# How to set cookie expiration date in asp.net

Tags: cookies, visual-studio-2005, datetime-generation

Good Day to All,

I am working with a small code, where I cant get my right hand part correctly

```
Response.Cookie("MyCookie").Expires=DateTime.FromString("2011-10-1");
```

Above cookie codes were used in my company's old project, I am updating the code and could not find a property named **FromString in DateTime**. Can anybody tell me an alternative to get desired result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a DateTime from a string, you would use [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

`DateTime.Parse("2011-10-1")`